# spring boot : how to run a test class only on jenkins?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, jenkins

We have a test class which I'd like to run only on Jenkins.

I think this can be achieved by checking the active spring profile (such as `jenkins`) or when the local machine name is `XYZ`.

The issue is, the loading of the application context fails when we try to run this on machines other than jenkins.

So I cannot check the profile or a parameter in the @Before method of the test class per se.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Config.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles("clusterMongo")
public class MongoTest {


    @Before
    public void setupClass() {

        // Ignore test if not running on white listed machines
        org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(AuthTools.isJenkins());   // wonT work !!

    }
```

...

Any ideas how we can achieve this?

Can i maybe use Conditional beans?

Comment: You are probably better off putting this in a separate integrationTest directory and only running that source set in Jenkins. Gradle supports this with an example here: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-integration-testing/ but there are ways to do it with any tool you use to build and run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing it programmatic, you have a declarative option.

You can configure the surefire plugin to skip certain tests for a certain Maven profile:

```
<profile>
<id>skip-test</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/MongoTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</profile>
```

On non-Jenkins run: `mvn test -Pskip-test`

Comment: cool, we also thought about this later on. This is probably one of the best ways to go.